# View exact java commands issued by SBT

Tags: java, sbt, jrebel

I'm trying to integrate jrebel with an SBT project. The following entry is in the build.scala file:

```
javaOptions ++= Seq("-javaagent:/path/to/jrebel.jar", "-Drebel.log=true", "-Drebel.log.file=/path/to/jrebel.log")
```

However, I'm not seeing any Jrebel output when SBT is started (or, for that matter, when files are updated) so I'd like to know if there is an SBT command/switch that can used to display the exact java commands that SBT is issuing? (maybe it's a versioning-format difference? I'm using SBT version 0.12.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did something strange.

If you wish to add jrebel to SBT you must add javaagent parameter to your command that invoke sbt-launch.jar Also don't forget properties file. ??? Your Build.scala is so huge? Incredible.

If you with to add jrebel to Scala application then SBT out of scope at all. Just start you app somewhere and it will reload recompiled classes. You need only specify where compiled class files is located. Then use sbt > ~package-bin. It is like maven, ant or any other build system.

IMHO javaOptions affect only specific tasks that fork jvm - like compilation, tests and so on.

Comment: Not being all-to-familiar with SBT, could you tell me what you're referring to by "properties file." (Aside, I put all of the build/test settings into build.scala, rather than having it spread out among other files. It's probably not the typical strategy, but it keeps everything centralized and personally, I find it easier to make logical adjustments.)

Comment: I mean that you must add rebel.xml with dir=/path/to/your/compiled/class/files to jar/war/whatever. JRebel only reload files. SBT only build. There is only relation between two different processes - file is changed at you storage, no shared settings, no shared option, no shared execution environment. And it is working well.

Comment: Got it. You message lead me to look at the sbt script and that that was indeed the issue. I have been using a "generic" start script, whereas the one with the framework (scalatra) had been using a modified version to get JRebel up and running. All is well, thank you. I still don't understand why Jrebel would not function when launched from WITHIN sbt - as my original setup was trying to do. It appears that SBT is launching JAVA to spawn the container service - which seems like the whole purpose for having the javaOptions parameter setting in the first place, yes? Thanks again.

Comment: Did you saw https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-sbt? Are you using plugin? How do you run your task? jetty-run? I think that it will be easy to investigate with SBT or plugin source code.

Comment: I read xsbt-web-plugin source code and I suspect that Jetty and SBT share the same JVM instance. If so you must add javaagent to your java process that starts sbt-launch.jar.

Comment: I saw that...tried it...wouldn't work. My issue was that I had a customized sbt launcher script that was Generic in nature. After I had modified it and "pathed" it, my version was running instead of any project-specific script - hence why even the project template you mention would not work as expected. (I had assumed the Jrebel integration came from within the build configuration settings, rather than the actual start-up script itself.)

Comment: I suspect that the only solution would be to add 'logLevel := Level.Debug' to your build.sbt and search for actual rebel.xml withing classpath. This situation is absolutely specific for your environment.

Comment: I saw that xsbt plugin and was going to dig in and see how they were pulling that off. My guess is that you right - which was something that the Jrebel tech support echoed as well when I was talking with them about sbt integration. Although part of me still thinks the javaOptions would work if configured/used properly.

Comment: I don't know neither your plugin version nor it original location. Look for example at https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/master/src/main/scala/Jetty7Runner.scala It is used classsloader and there is no rebel.xml. Please use GitHub code search. You will easily find any suitable information.