# sbt: show the java command invoked by the run task

Tags: sbt

Can I make `sbt run` echo the exact java command it is invoking?

This question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473259/view-exact-java-commands-issued-by-sbt), but the OP's issue was resolved without answering the question, so I'm asking again.

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought this would do it:

```
set logLevel := Level.Debug
```

It produces a torrent of info out of most commands, but, sadly, not a forked `run`.

Looking at https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13.0/run/src/main/scala/sbt/Run.scala , there seems to be a conspicuous lack of calls to `log.debug(...)`. Same in https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13.0/run/src/main/scala/sbt/Fork.scala. You might patch either or both of those source files to log what you want logged and rebuild sbt.

If that seems too ambitious, not sure what to suggest other than starting with `inspect run` and then doing `inspect` and `show` on the various settings listed under "Dependencies:"; this will at least you show all the different pieces of information that are feeding into the `run` task.